# How can I pause promise until I get a user action in js, firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks

I'm using firebase and problem occurred at OTP verification.
I want to separate OTP send and OTP verify but firebase doesn't support right now I think.
I'll show my codes.

This is Verification code sending button function.
purpose is send a code and wait until code is updated and then verifying
But I can't make this code wait until onVerify executed.

```
const OnSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dbService
      .collection('users')
      .where('phoneNumber', '==', nationNum)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapShot) => {
        //send verification
        return provider.verifyPhoneNumber(verifyNum, recaptchaVerifier);
      })
      .then((verificationId) => {
        ///complete send code
        /// Here is a Problem!! I want to pause until onVerify execution or useState changed.
         return firebaseInstance.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verify,
            verifyNum,
          );
      })
      .then((phoneCredential) => {
        ///verify success
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        ///verify failed
      });
```

Here's a onVerify
I'll put a code and start verify phone number

```
const onVerify = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputNum.length === 6) {
      setVerifyNum(inputNum);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You can pause a promise by returning another promise within, then you can control the state using that promise instead.

Comment: @zanderwar thanks for your comment. Can you recommend me some more detailed document? I want to refer some example codes

Comment: Take a look at an example [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/six-things-might-know-promises/)

Comment: How do you key-in the verification code (`verifyNum`)?

Comment: Pausing promise is not an efficient approach. Store `verificationId` in state and when the user is done with entering OTP (say verify button click) trigger another function which takes  `verificationId` from state and proceeds with `PhoneAuthProvider.credential`

Comment: @p2pdops I used this approach at the first time but it didn't work. But I'll try one more thanks!

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I omitted that part in the upper code